# Java - Intellij - Enum formatting

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, formatting

I have been trying to find formatting options in IntelliJ for this but can't seem to find anything.

Is it even possible to have a formatting similar to this?

I want this formatting beacuse the enum gets really long and with my tiny screen it is kinda impossible to read very very long lines.

Thank you

```
enum MyEnum {

   FIRST(new Object(),
         new Banana(false),
         new Banana(true));

   SECOND(new Object());

public MyEnum(Object object, Banana... bananas){
       this.object = object;
       this.bananas = bananas;
   }
}
```

Comment: Tips: let's try to adjust the code style to find best suitable for you in: `File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java`

Comment: @Tom, the thing is, that every new parameter in the enum object is on a new line.

Comment: new Object() <- first line
new Banana(false), new Banana(true) <- second line

Comment: Yeah i just realised i made a mistake and did not press enter when i was typing the example. I edited the original post now.